# Check input against set and run operations

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create an error-handle for a user input. My current attempt is running both `if` and `else` for any input. I am trying to have operations run if `True` and to repeat the question if `False` without running any operations.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# get link and parse
page = requests.get('https://www.finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&ft=4')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

# return 'Title's for each filter
# to be used as columns in dataframe
titles = soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class': 'screener-combo-title'})
title_list = []
for t in titles:
    t = t.stripped_strings
    t = ' '.join(t)
    title_list.append(t)


# finding filters-cells tag id's
# to be used to build url
filters = soup.find_all('select', attrs={'data-filter': True})
filter_list = []
for f in filters:
    filter_list.append(f.get('data-filter'))


# finding selectable values per cell
cell_list = []
for f in filters:
    options = f.find_all('option', attrs={'value': True})
    option_list = []    # list needs to stay inside
    for option in options:
        if option['value'] != "":
            option_list.append(option['value'])
    cell_list.append(option_list)

# create dict to build data frame with
final_dict = {}
for key in title_list:
    for value in cell_list:
        final_dict[key] = value
        cell_list.remove(value)
        break

# build data frame and insert values
max_element = max([len(v) for v in final_dict.values()])
for k in final_dict:
    final_dict[k] = final_dict[k] + [''] * (max_element - len(final_dict[k]))
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(final_dict)


# find non-nan values
def valueFinder():
    column_check = input('Choose which column...\n')
    if column_check in df.columns:
        no_value = df.loc[df[column_check] == ''].index[0]
        print(df[column_check].head(no_value))
    else:
        print('\nIt seems you chose a wrong option. Try again.\n')
        valueFinder()


valueFinder()
```

My result is:

```
Choose which column...
Index

It seems you chose a wrong option. Try again.
Choose which column...
Index

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Desired result if `True`:

```
Choose which column...
Exchange
0     amex
1     nasd
2     nyse
3    modal
Name: Exchange, dtype: object

Process finished with exit code 0
```

edit: noticed I used `input` instead of `print` in `else` and I also recalled the function in `else`. Changed code to reflect.

Answer (score 1):

replace this line:

```
if column_check in cell_set:
```

By this:

```
if column_check in df.columns:
```

I tested it out and it worked fine for me like the desired result you want. 
The dataset is built correctly.
You just have to use the dataframe attribute 'columns'.

Comment: `Choose which column...
indee

It seems you chose a wrong option. Try again.
Choose which column...
Index

Process finished with exit code 0`

Works fine if input is correct first time, doesn't work if input is not correct first time.

Comment: I found the problem, I used `input` in the `else` statement instead of `print` and recalling the function

Answer (score 1):

Running this

```
for value in cell_list:
    final_dict[key] = value
    cell_list.remove(value)
    break
```

Will cause `cell_list` to become empty afterward. Also, if `cell_list` were not emptied at that point, it would be a list of other lists*, which means you cannot call `set()` on it.

*something like `[['amex', 'nasd', 'nyse', 'modal'], ['sp500', 'dji'], ['basicmaterials', 'conglomerates', ...`